# subplot ploterrhist in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
for n = 1:2
    for n = 1:100

        % some logics

    end
    subplot(2,n,1);
    ploterrhist(error)
end
```

I only get one graph and I don't even see subplot. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
for i = 1:2
  for j = 1:100
    % some logics
  end
   subplot(2,1,i);
   ploterrhist(...)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I used the same `n` over. I changed to 1:2 and `i`. But they still show up as one graph and overwrites thep preivous one.